# Using cell (returned from cellForRow method) in didSelectRow method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am stuck at a place where I want to add an image on top of an image button such that the image of the button changes when I click on it. I have to write the logic in didSelectRow method. Hence I need to write the following line to get that image added:

```
button=[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,0,40,40];
button.addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonPressed:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag=indexPath.row;
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview: button];
```

Although this works when I write the above code in cellForRow , this doesn't work in didSelectRow as cell is not defined in this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (UIButton *button in cell.subviews) {
        if (button.tag==indexPath.row) {
            [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"another.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in didSelectRow to get the cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```